# how to select all records which exists in last 6 months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone suggest me how to select all the records which exists in the last N month?

N would be parameter.

I've written below sub-query to return the desired result. but this is not dynamic since i can not pass N number of month to select last n month records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT supplier_code
FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
WHERE supplier_code IN
(SELECT supplier_code
 FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
 WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) = '2020-03-01')
 AND supplier_code IN
(SELECT supplier_code
 FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
 WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) = '2020-02-01')
 AND supplier_code IN
(SELECT supplier_code
 FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
 WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) = '2020-01-01')
 AND supplier_code IN
(SELECT supplier_code
 FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
 WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) = '2019-12-01')
 AND supplier_code IN
(SELECT supplier_code
 FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
 WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) = '2019-11-01')
```

Comment: Have you tried [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql), like `WHERE dbo.ConvertStringToDate(period_start_date) >= DATEADD(month, -N, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))`? This is converting current time to date, then subtracting N months. Update: oh, you need records which occur in each of the last N months, right?

Comment: Still there? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the suppliers which have at least one entry for each of the last N months:

```
declare @N as INT = 6;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT supplier_code, CONVERT(varchar(6), CONVERT(date, period_start_date), 112) start_month
    FROM API_StockAndSaleHeader
    WHERE CONVERT(date, period_start_date) >= DATEADD(month, -@N, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
)
SELECT supplier_code
FROM CTE
GROUP BY supplier_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= @N;
```

This first gets an auxiliary set of distinct supplier_codes + months, in order to know which suppliers had at least one record in the last 6 months. The trick is to convert the date to varchar and trim it to 6 characters, getting a `yyyymm` format. Then you just need those with at least N records, which will mean all N months have data. I used `>=` just to play safe, it depends on how you are dividing months. Every 30/31? 30 days counting from today?

Note I'm using `CONVERT` to convert to a date instead. BTW, storing dates as other types is a bad thing.

With this data, it will display just `Supplier 1`:

```
select 'Supplier 1' supplier_code, '10/10/2019' period_start_date into API_StockAndSaleHeader
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '11/11/2019'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '12/12/2019'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '01/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '02/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '03/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '03/15/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '04/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 1', '05/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '02/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '03/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '03/15/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '03/22/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '03/26/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '04/01/2020'
union all
select 'Supplier 2', '05/01/2020'
```

Note Supplier 2 has more than 6 entries in the last month, but has no entries for each of the last N months.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #API_StockAndSaleHeader 
    (
        supplier_code int,
        period_start_date DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO #API_StockAndSaleHeader (supplier_code, period_start_date) VALUES
    (1, '2020-05-01'),
    (1, '2020-04-01'),
    (1, '2020-04-15'), -- This one should not show up.
    (2, '2020-05-01'),
    (2, '2020-04-01'),
    (2, '2020-03-01'), -- This one should show up.
    (2, '2020-02-01'),
    (2, '2020-01-01')

    DECLARE @months int = 3

    SELECT supplier_code 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT supplier_code, DATEPART(year, period_start_date) as [Year], DATEPART(month, period_start_date) as [month]--DISTINCT supplier_code
        FROM #API_StockAndSaleHeader 
        WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, @months, period_start_date) >= GETDATE()
        GROUP BY supplier_code, DATEPART(year, period_start_date), DATEPART(month, period_start_date)
    ) A
    GROUP BY supplier_code
    HAVING COUNT(supplier_code) >= @months

    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#API_StockAndSaleHeader') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Temp
    END
```

Comment: No need to use a transaction and also delete the table. Anyway, you are deleting `#Temp`, which doesn't exist. Shahab already has that table, so he will need to remove many things from the script for it to work for him. It's better to post the script that OP needs, and then, in a separate block, include a test case for the rest of us without the data. `@firstDayOfCurrentMonth` is not used, and you don't need a `distinct` if you are already grouping by that single field.

Comment: @Andrew I just always write begin/rollback before writing any code. It's not a bad habit to have. Also I wanted to have testable code by anyone that does not have the table so that I can prove it gives the correct result.

Comment: Hi @Danieboy ! Thanks for providing quick result. i got it. you both are awesome.